# Changing database structure of Django in server

Tags: python, django, database, django-models

When we work with Django in local environment, we change the structure of the Data Base using Command Prompt through **migration**. 
But for using Django in server, i don't now how can i apply such changes? How can i type commands to change Data Base structure? Is it a good way to upload site files every time that i do some change again.

Comment: If you commit the migration files in your source code..then when you deploy to your server you can run the migration the same as if on your local. Is that what you mean?

Comment: In a nutshell, i made a website in local, after putting it in server, now i want to add some columns to some tables, how?

Comment: You ran `makemigrations` on local, then `migrate`? You can log into your server and get your source code and django on there and run the same commands. You have already adjusted your python database models and ran those commands locally right?

Comment: It doesn't matter if you are making the changes to your local development environment or production server. You still use `migrate` command.

Answer (score 1):

The whole point of migrations is that you run them on both your local database and in production, to keep them in sync.

Comment: Agreed..as is what I implied on my comment. He's asking for more details because he hasn't done a deploy and migration on a server before.